# How to build a rust and python project into one exe executable?

Tags: python, rust, pyo3, maturin

I have a folder in which there are two folders one of them is called src and it contains the file lib.rs, and the second one is myPy which contains python files and one main.py file where other python files are imported, I use pyo3 to connect rust to python, can you tell me how to build the project into one executable exe file?

Comment: Does Python executes Rust (Python is starting first), or Rust is executing Python?

Comment: Python executes Rust, I import the rust file into a python file.

Comment: Then you can try Pyinstaller or cxFreeze to build your python program into an executable.

Comment: Here is a dicussion I found about using pyo3 with Pyinstaller: https://github.com/PyO3/pyo3/discussions/3341 . It doesn't seem like it would work well. But you can give it a shot.

Comment: I'll text you if it works.

Comment: everything worked when I added the line --add-data="path to .env" to pyinstaller